# Wie verwende ich das Wort "Apostroph" morphologisch richtig?

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, morphology, greek

Anlässlich einer wiederkehrenden Frage in dieser Runde zur Verwendung des Auslassungszeichens (') bei der Schreibung bestimmter Wörter oder Wortfügungen stoße ich auf das Problem, dass ich nach wie vor nicht sicher bin, wie ich das Wort ***Apostroph*** grammatisch richtig verwenden soll.

Welche der folgenden Varianten ist richtig?

- Hier sollte man kein Apostroph setzen
- Hier sollte man keinen Apostroph setzen
- Hier sollte man keinen Apostrophen setzen

Im Widerspruch zu der von mir lange gehegten naiven Meinung, dass das Wort ***das*** Apostroph heißt, belehrt mich der Duden, dass es ***der*** Apostroph heißt. Damit erhebt sich die Frage nach der gebeugten Formen.

Im Singular

- der Apostroph
- des Apostrophs? des Apostrophen?
- dem Apostroph? dem Apostrophen?
- den Apostroph? den Apostrophen?

Im Plural

- die Apostrophe [sagt der Duden]
- der Apostrophen?
- den Apostrophen?
- die Apostrophen?

Vergleichsweise:

- der Blumentopf
- des Blumentopfs
- dem Blumentopf
- den Blumentopf

Aber auch

- der Fremde
- des Fremden
- dem Fremden
- den Fremden

Interessant wäre in diesem Zusammenhang auch die korrekte Verwendung anderer aus dem Griechischen kommender Wörter auf -ph

- das Apokryph
- das Kenotaph
- das Morph
- (weitere?)

Comment: Wenn du dich vom Duden beim Genus belehren lässt, warum dann nicht auch bei der Deklination?

Comment: Schau dir mal das Beispiel im DWDS an: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Apostroph. Übrigens hätte ich bis eben auch gedacht, dass der Apostroph ein Neutrum wäre.

Comment: @IQV  Wo würde ich im Duden eine volle Deklination des Wortes finden?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  - Danke, das ist eine gute Quelle (auch mit einer sauberen Etymologie dabei). Demnach wäre der Akkusativ: *Ich setze **einen Apostroph***.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Siehe die [Online-Ausgabe des Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Apostroph), Abschnitt "Grammatik".

Comment: @Lykanion  Oh, in der Tat, samt ganzer Deklinationstabelle. Möchtest du das nicht als Antwort hier eingeben?

Comment: Alles was du wissen willst, findest du hier: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apostroph Wenn du Deklinations- und Flexionstabellen suchst, ist Wiktionary die beste Wahl. Ich schaue schon lange nicht mehr im viel zu unübersichtlichen und oft unvollständigen Duden nach.

Answer (score 1):

```
            Singular        Plural
Nominativ   der Apostroph   die Apostrophe
Genitiv     des Apostrophs  der Apostrophe
Dativ       dem Apostroph   den Apostrophen
Akkusativ   den Apostroph   die Apostrophe
```

siehe: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Apostroph) => `Hier sollte man keinen Apostroph setzen.`